Validation for a collection of objects
I am writing the backend part of an application in which I want to implement the ability to accept and validate for each object in the list.
I know about two annotations that can do this:

@Valid is fine, but I need to use it to pass the name of the group to be used for validation (some classes have specific implementations for adding and updating data);
@Validated - accepts the group, but does not validate each compression object.
Are there any settings in Spring Boot that can force @Validated to validate each object in the list?

Here is a sample code:
public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> addStream(
    @Validated(InsertRequest.class) @RequestBody List<FacultyRequest> requests,
    Principal principal
) {
    var response = service.addValue(requests, principal.getName());
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .body(response);
}


An option to specify which group should be used for the @Valid annotation is to use the @ConvertGroup annotation to use your own group instead of the default one.
public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> addStream(
        @RequestBody List<@Valid @ConvertGroup(to = InsertRequest.class) AudienceRequest> requests,
        Principal principal
) {
    var response = service.addValue(requests, principal.getName());
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .body(response);
}

